# SpriteKit - iAds squeezes scene

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, iad

I'm having troubles with iAds in SpriteKit.

When the Banner pops up it sqeezes the scene. 
I used `scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;`
Also with every other scaleMode it i not working.

Is there any chance or type of code that the iAdBanner is just overlaying my scene? Just like doing a sprite over another one. 
Except doing it in the Storyboard!!